# не отображается venv

Tags: python, venv

по какой причине при создании проекта не появляется venv в левом верхем углу под названием проекта?И как это исправить.Я использую пайчарм. Спасибо за помощь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, при создании проекта неверно указаны настройки виртуального окружения. Чтобы создать новое, нужно выбрать пункт, отмеченный красным цветом на скриншоте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]